Failing to build parachain using try-runtime
I am currently trying to build runtime with --features try-runtime but getting the following errors


I added getrandom crate with "js" features to the runtime Cargo.toml file but I am then getting the following errors


The parachain is currently running on Polkadot v 1.0 (full code here). What would be the best way to resolve these build errors?

The issue was resolved after adding missing try-runtime dependencies in all pallets and removing [pallet-name]/std dependencies from pallet-circuit-vacuum try-runtime config
